# Thymeleaf labels not returning values to server

Tags: html, spring, forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am finding it difficult to retrieve data from a web page when that data was initially passed in from the controller layer.

I am using Thymeleaf 3 and Spring boot v1. I have a webMVC controller which is passing an object to the template. The object looks something like this (pseudo-code):

```
public class Person{
   // Nested object retrieved from various data sources
   // and passed to the UI
   private Address address;
   private Job job;

   // Form values I want to retrieve from UI
   private String formValue1;
   private String formValue2;

   // getters/setters
}
```

My html page is divided into two sections. One section displays most of the Person values, while the other section includes a basic form. When the form is submitted, I want the form values plus ALL original values returned to the server.

What I'm finding is that it seems Thymeleaf will only retrieve values which are in the form, which means I have to stretch the form across both sections of the page, even though the user will only fill out one section of the page. So now the html looks as follows:

```
        <html>
         <!--header/body/etc -->
           <form th:object="${person}" th:action="@{/person/id}" method="post">
              <!-- Form Inputs -->
                <input type="text" th:field="${person.formValue1}"/>
                <input type="text" th:field="${person.formValue2}"/>
              <!-- Values not used in form, but included so they will be sent back 
                   to server -->
                <input type="text" th:field="${person.address.city}" readonly="readonly"/>
                <input type="text" th:field="${person.address.street}" 
readonly="readonly"/>
                <input type="text" th:field="${person.job.title}" readonly="readonly"/>
           </form>
        </html>
```

Additionally, it seems that Thymeleaf can only retrieve values that have the attribute `th:field`, but `th:field` is only assignable to the `<input/>` element (as far as I know), so any long text I have is truncated to the normal length of an input field, which is rather limited.

So I'm wondering if anyone can help with the following questions:

1. Can Thymeleaf return values which are not within a form (but returned when the form is submitted)
2. Is `th:field` the only option I can use for sending data back? (I've successfully displayed data with `th:text`, but no luck sending anything back).

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure, the issue with two forms, is the problem about your object not being populated with all the values?

Comment: Only one form, but it contains values which aren't needed by the form. They're include so they will be sent back to the server. I've updated with html example

Answer (score 0):

**Can Thymeleaf return values which are not within a form (but returned when the form is submitted)**

This is more about how HTML forms and POST in HTTP works here. HTML form will send whole data within and Thymeleaf will bind that data to an object in your controller. So if you want all the values you should in fact wrap it all in a single form - this is a good way to go. If the case is that you don't want to display all the fields you could use hidden fields.

If you still would like to keep the data in separate forms for some reason you could try to work around it:

- By using JavaScript to collect data from both forms and send it
- Try to name both forms the same. I am not sure about it but it might work

I wouldn't recommend any of those anyway. Try to keep it simple.

**Is th:field the only option I can use for sending data back? (I've successfully displayed data with th:text, but no luck sending anything back)**

For a long text you can use textarea.